# Bluetooth on Ubuntu 13.10 Sony Vaio- Can I manage multiple USB bluetooth adapters?

Tags: 13.10, bluetooth, a2dp

first post, so bear with me.  I was wondering if it's possible to manage multiple USB bluetooth adapters and run them at the same time.  The computer recognizes both when they are plugged in, but prioritizes one over the other for normal bluetooth connections.

I would love to be able to connect to multiple bluetooth speakers (each with their own receiver) in a setting like this:

**Computer USB Adapter A to Speaker Receiver A**

**Computer USB Adapter B to Speaker Receiver B**

**Audio output to both A and B the same.**

I know I can't use one dongle to connect to two speakers, which is why I'm asking.

Here is my info:

```
LSUSB

Bus 002 Device 003: ID 0a12:0001 Cambridge Silicon Radio, Ltd Bluetooth Dongle (HCI mode)  
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 0a12:0001 Cambridge Silicon Radio, Ltd Bluetooth Dongle (HCI mode)
```

Also

```
HCICONFIG

hci1:   Type: BR/EDR  Bus: USB
    BD Address: 00:11:22:98:76:54  ACL MTU: 1021:4  SCO MTU: 180:1
    UP RUNNING PSCAN ISCAN 
    RX bytes:398 acl:0 sco:0 events:17 errors:0
    TX bytes:305 acl:0 sco:0 commands:19 errors:3

hci0:   Type: BR/EDR  Bus: USB
    BD Address: 00:11:22:98:76:54  ACL MTU: 1021:4  SCO MTU: 180:1
    UP RUNNING 
    RX bytes:750 acl:0 sco:0 events:45 errors:0
    TX bytes:390 acl:0 sco:0 commands:30 errors:2
```

And Finally

```
hci0:   Type: BR/EDR  Bus: USB
    BD Address: 00:11:22:98:76:54  ACL MTU: 1021:4  SCO MTU: 180:1
    UP RUNNING 
    RX bytes:1027 acl:0 sco:0 events:48 errors:0
    TX bytes:399 acl:0 sco:0 commands:33 errors:2
    Features: 0xff 0x3e 0x09 0x76 0x80 0x01 0x00 0x80
    Packet type: DM1 DM3 DM5 DH1 DH3 DH5 HV1 HV2 HV3 
    Link policy: RSWITCH HOLD SNIFF 
    Link mode: SLAVE ACCEPT 
    Name: 'barf'
    Class: 0x6e0100
    Service Classes: Networking, Rendering, Capturing, Audio, Telephony
    Device Class: Computer, Uncategorized
    HCI Version: 2.0 (0x3)  Revision: 0x50
    LMP Version: 2.0 (0x3)  Subversion: 0x3
    Manufacturer: Mitel Semiconductor (16)
```

Thanks so much!!!

Answer (score 0):

No, at least I think probably you could't but because both USB Bluetooth dongles have the same MAC address. As you can notice, all Mitel Semiconductor bluetooth adapters have the same address, 00:11:22:98:76:54.
Usually, they look like:

[image]

With a different dongle, try [this guide](http://www.heatxsink.com/entry/how-to-pair-a-bluetooth-device-from-command-line-on-linux) to connect device in a terminal.

Comment: Thank you!  After much experimentation I came to the same conclusion.  I would also not recommend this dongle.  Although it is immediately recognized, the connection is not reliable.  Thanks again!